# Linux Mint で blueman パッケージのインストールに失敗する

Tags: linux, ubuntu

blueman パッケージのインストールに失敗します。原因は何でしょうか？

使用しているOSはLinux Mint 21.2です。

```
$ sudo apt-get install blueman
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 blueman : 依存: python3 (< 3.11) しかし、3.11.4-5+b1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。
```

Comment: `依存: python3 (< 3.11)`の表記だと、`3.11未満`なので`3.10以下`が必要なのでは？ 3.10系に版数を落と(すのかインストール対象版数を明記するのか)してからインストールしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: [Qiita での質問状況](https://qiita.com/rabt1100/questions/2d7f2d478eddd0a350da) を見る限り、ディストリビューションは Linux Mint のようですが、既にコメントがついている通りバージョン情報が必要です。/ `apt list python3` で Python 3.x パッケージのバージョンも確認してみてください。

Comment: 手元では再現しませんでしたので、一般的なアドバイスとなりますが、`apt update`、`apt install --fix-broken` などを試してみて下さい。
`apt show blueman` の結果も役に立つかも知れません。
あと、Python3.11 のバージョンが少し気になります。3.11.4-5+b1 がイントールされようとしている、というメッセージですが、Mint 21.2はUbuntu22.04ベースなので、[現在は3.11.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/python3.11)のはずで、実際に手元ではそうです。
何かリポジトリの追加などがされているのかも知れません。